# Android layout cutted button background

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

A small part of the button background (`button.png`) gets cut off. Here the `res/layout/activity_home_screen.xml` file:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeScreen"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_repeat"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:stretchColumns="0" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_margin="10dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/news_button"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:text="@string/news_button"

                android:onClick="gotoNews" />

    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_margin="10dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/events_button"
            style="@style/AppBaseTheme"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:text="@string/events_button"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:onClick="gotoEvents" />

    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_margin="10dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nav_button"
            style="@style/AppBaseTheme"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:text="@string/nav_button"
            android:textSize="40sp"

            android:onClick="gotoNav" />

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

How to not have the background cut off?

Comment: can you show button.png , i think it is in image file?

Comment: Here you can see the problem much better: http://puu.sh/1XpIp

Comment: button.png, as requested: _http://puu.sh/1Xqd9_

Comment: I've found the problem in your xml code, check answer by me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use LinearLayout instead of TableLayout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="20dp"
tools:context=".HomeScreen" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/news_button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:onClick="gotoNews"
    android:text="@string/news_button"
    android:textSize="40sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/events_button"
    style="@style/AppBaseTheme"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:onClick="gotoEvents"
    android:text="@string/events_button"
    android:textSize="40sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/nav_button"
    style="@style/AppBaseTheme"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:onClick="gotoNav"
    android:text="@string/nav_button"
    android:textSize="40sp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you've put margine in

check out

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"



    android:stretchColumns="0" >

    <TableRow

         >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/news_button"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:text="News"

                />

    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_margin="10dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/events_button"
            style="@style/AppBaseTheme"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:text="Events"
            android:textSize="40sp"
             />

    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_margin="10dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nav_button"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:text="Nave"
            android:textSize="40sp"

             />

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, but I've used the solution in answer 1.